# Jenkins fails after updating in AWS EC2 machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2

I have Jenkins installed in an EC2 machine in AWS. I tried to install the slack plugin and it break the other plugins, so I tried updating Jenkins version to make it work again and now I cannot event start it. I get the following message:

```
Starting jenkins (via systemctl):  Failed to start jenkins.service: Unit is not loaded properly: Invalid argument.
See system logs and 'systemctl status jenkins.service' for details.
                                                           [FAILED]
```

I have also tried to delete Jenkins completely following this [guide](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/remove-jenkins): to then reinstall it following the [Jenkins in AWS guide](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/tutorials/tutorial-for-installing-jenkins-on-AWS/#downloading-and-installing-jenkins). But it is still not working. At some point when I did the  `journalctl -xe` I got this error (I cant remember what I did to get there but at least I saved this log trace):

```
Unit jenkins.service has begun starting up.
Sep 20 16:39:49 ip-10-10-3-149.ec2.internal jenkins[23035]: Sep 20, 2022 4:39:49 PM executable.Main verifyJavaVersion
Sep 20 16:39:49 ip-10-10-3-149.ec2.internal jenkins[23035]: SEVERE: Running with Java class version 52, which is older than
Sep 20 16:39:49 ip-10-10-3-149.ec2.internal jenkins[23035]: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: 52.0
Sep 20 16:39:49 ip-10-10-3-149.ec2.internal jenkins[23035]: at executable.Main.verifyJavaVersion(Main.java:145)
Sep 20 16:39:49 ip-10-10-3-149.ec2.internal jenkins[23035]: at executable.Main.main(Main.java:109)
Sep 20 16:39:49 ip-10-10-3-149.ec2.internal jenkins[23035]: Jenkins requires Java versions [17, 11] but you are running wit
Sep 20 16:39:49 ip-10-10-3-149.ec2.internal jenkins[23035]: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: 52.0
Sep 20 16:39:49 ip-10-10-3-149.ec2.internal jenkins[23035]: at executable.Main.verifyJavaVersion(Main.java:145)
Sep 20 16:39:49 ip-10-10-3-149.ec2.internal jenkins[23035]: at executable.Main.main(Main.java:109)
Sep 20 16:39:49 ip-10-10-3-149.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Failed to start Jenkins Continuous Integration Server.
-- Subject: Unit jenkins.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit jenkins.service has failed.
--
```

So I though I had finally found the error, I checked the java -version and it was saying java1.8. Therefore I changed it with `alternatives --config java` and set it to:

```
java-11-openjdk.x86_64 (/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.16.0.8-1.amzn2.0.1.x86_64/bin/java)
```

I have also added this path to `/etc/rc.d/init.d/jenkins`. Now when I get the java -version I get this:

```
openjdk version "11.0.16" 2022-07-19 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Red_Hat-11.0.16.0.8-1.amzn2.0.1) (build 11.0.16+8-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Red_Hat-11.0.16.0.8-1.amzn2.0.1) (build 11.0.16+8-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
```

when I try to get the status of jenkins with `systemctl status jenkins.service -l` I get:

```
● jenkins.service
   Loaded: error (Reason: Invalid argument)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/jenkins.service.d
           └─override.conf
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Tue 2022-09-20 16:39:49 UTC; 15h ago
 Main PID: 23035 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Sep 20 16:57:30 ip-10-10-3-149.ec2.internal systemd[1]: jenkins.service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
Sep 20 16:57:43 ip-10-10-3-149.ec2.internal systemd[1]: jenkins.service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
Sep 21 07:15:59 ip-10-10-3-149.ec2.internal systemd[1]: jenkins.service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
Sep 21 07:20:02 ip-10-10-3-149.ec2.internal systemd[1]: jenkins.service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
Sep 21 07:23:12 ip-10-10-3-149.ec2.internal systemd[1]: jenkins.service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
Sep 21 07:23:20 ip-10-10-3-149.ec2.internal systemd[1]: jenkins.service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
Sep 21 07:24:26 ip-10-10-3-149.ec2.internal systemd[1]: jenkins.service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
Sep 21 07:30:58 ip-10-10-3-149.ec2.internal systemd[1]: jenkins.service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
Sep 21 07:31:06 ip-10-10-3-149.ec2.internal systemd[1]: jenkins.service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
Sep 21 07:48:04 ip-10-10-3-149.ec2.internal systemd[1]: jenkins.service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
```

and when I use `journalctl -xe` I get:

```
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit session-120.scope has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Sep 21 07:40:01 ip-10-10-3-149.ec2.internal CROND[842]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Sep 21 07:41:28 ip-10-10-3-149.ec2.internal dhclient[3121]: XMT: Solicit on eth0, interval 131610ms.
Sep 21 07:43:39 ip-10-10-3-149.ec2.internal dhclient[3121]: XMT: Solicit on eth0, interval 118630ms.
Sep 21 07:45:38 ip-10-10-3-149.ec2.internal dhclient[3121]: XMT: Solicit on eth0, interval 121300ms.
Sep 21 07:46:59 ip-10-10-3-149.ec2.internal sshd[3483]: Received disconnect from 92.255.85.69 port 28784:
Sep 21 07:46:59 ip-10-10-3-149.ec2.internal sshd[3483]: Disconnected from 92.255.85.69 port 28784 [preaut
Sep 21 07:47:04 ip-10-10-3-149.ec2.internal dhclient[3075]: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 10.10.3.1 port 67 (xid
Sep 21 07:47:04 ip-10-10-3-149.ec2.internal dhclient[3075]: DHCPACK from 10.10.3.1 (xid=0x18dc5aad)
Sep 21 07:47:04 ip-10-10-3-149.ec2.internal NET[3542]: dhclient: Locked /run/dhclient/resolv.lock
Sep 21 07:47:04 ip-10-10-3-149.ec2.internal dhclient[3075]: bound to 10.10.3.149 -- renewal in 1618 secon
Sep 21 07:47:04 ip-10-10-3-149.ec2.internal ec2net[3561]: [get_meta] Querying IMDS for meta-data/network/
Sep 21 07:47:04 ip-10-10-3-149.ec2.internal ec2net[3562]: [get_meta] Getting token for IMDSv2.
Sep 21 07:47:04 ip-10-10-3-149.ec2.internal ec2net[3565]: [get_meta] Trying to get http://169.254.169.254
Sep 21 07:47:04 ip-10-10-3-149.ec2.internal ec2net[3570]: [remove_aliases] Removing aliases of eth0
Sep 21 07:47:39 ip-10-10-3-149.ec2.internal dhclient[3121]: XMT: Solicit on eth0, interval 116180ms.
Sep 21 07:48:03 ip-10-10-3-149.ec2.internal sudo[3947]:     root : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/root ; USER=root ; CO
Sep 21 07:48:03 ip-10-10-3-149.ec2.internal sudo[3947]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user r
Sep 21 07:48:03 ip-10-10-3-149.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Reloading.
Sep 21 07:48:04 ip-10-10-3-149.ec2.internal systemd[1]: jenkins.service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecSto
Sep 21 07:48:04 ip-10-10-3-149.ec2.internal sudo[3947]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user r
Sep 21 07:48:09 ip-10-10-3-149.ec2.internal sudo[4019]:     root : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/root ; USER=root ; CO
Sep 21 07:48:09 ip-10-10-3-149.ec2.internal sudo[4019]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user r
Sep 21 07:48:09 ip-10-10-3-149.ec2.internal sudo[4019]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user r
```

I have tried also the solution in [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/395131/systemd-service-lacks-both-execstart-and-execstop-setting-refusing). I am not sure what else I can try.

UPDATE: this is how my jenkins unit looks like (systemctl cat jenkins):

```
# /etc/systemd/system/jenkins.service
[Service]
Environment="JENKINS_PORT=8000"

# /etc/systemd/system/jenkins.service.d/override.conf
[Service]
Environment="JENKINS_PORT=8000"
```

Comment: How does your jenkins unit look like (`systemctl cat jenkins`)?

Comment: Your jenkins unit file is missing start and stop scripts. Check https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/systemd-services/ and make changes to your unit file accordingly. I would first add start and stop files and try. Not much knowlege of how jenkins unit file should be.

Comment: @Riz omg thanks! That indeed worked, I replaced the file with the service configurations in the link you sent and it worked. You can send it as a response so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the logs, the unit file is missing start and stop scripts which can be confirmed by
`systemctl cat jenkins`.
According to [Jenkins docs](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/systemd-services/), the systemd file needed changes.Copying and overriding the unit file with the one given in the docs can solve the problem.